# Add/Edit Element In ServiceBehaviors in RunTime

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I write the serviceBehaviors section by coding in C # at runtime?

[ServiceBehaviors Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae5lX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is for reference:

[Specifying Service Run-Time Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/specifying-service-run-time-behavior)

[Specifying Client Run-Time Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/specifying-client-run-time-behavior)

Comment: tanks Theobald Du. but i want to add or edit elements in app.config xml file in Runtime.

Comment: If you want to apply your changes at runtime, it is impossible to be effective. If you want to achieve your changes, you need to update the service.